# Clear session value in scala

Tags: java, javascript, scala, playframework

I am using play framework (Java version) for a project and I came up across a situation to clear a session value inside javascript code. I have used following code but it doesn't compile.

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
    $('#errorMsg').text('');
    @session.put("errorMsg",null);// It didn't work
    @session().remove("errorMsg");// It didn't work either
}
```

I know it uses scala here, so I gone through the documentation & found following approach in this [link](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaSessionFlash).

```
You can remove any value from the incoming session the same way:

Ok("Theme reset!").withSession(
  session - "theme")
```

but I couldn't exactly understand how it could be done from Javascript. Is there an equivalent to `session().remove("errorMsg");` to do in Javascript?
First of all, is it reasonable to do it in Javascript rather than doing it in server side?

Please Advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its not a good idea to remove or change the session from the javascript, because *"Play Framework uses stateless sessions"*. There is no state stored on the server side, rather, all the state is stored in the session cookie. To validate a session, Play signs the sessions using a secret key, and validates the signature when a request with a session cookie arrives. If cookie was modified from the javascirpt, then the signature would not match, and so Play would reject the session cookie.

so its better that you change it from your server side.

in **scala**

```
Ok("Bye").withNewSession
```

in **java**

```
session().clear();
```

Comment: Thanks.. It seems so meaningful. :)